# Error in converting double to int

Tags: c, casting, int, double

I have a code that has 2 doubles as an input and then I want to convert it to 2 ints. I think it's either a problem with dereferencing or my casting syntax is off. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double * int1;
    double * int2;

    printf("Put in two numbers:");
    scanf("%lf", int1);
    scanf("%lf", int2);

    int a = (int) (int1);
    int b = (int) (int2);

    printf("%d\n%d", a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it you could do this two ways one using pointers and dynamic memory on the heap and one with automatic values.

## Pointers with dynamically allocated memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    double * int1 = malloc(sizeof(double));
    double * int2 = malloc(sizeof(double));

    printf("Put in two numbers:");
    scanf("%lf", int1);
    scanf("%lf", int2);

    int a = (int) *int1;
    int b = (int) *int2;

    printf("%d\n%d", a, b);
    free(int1);
    free(int2);
}
```

## Automatic values allocated on the system stack

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double int1;
    double int2;

    printf("Put in two numbers:");
    scanf("%lf", &int1);
    scanf("%lf", &int2);

    int a = (int) int1;
    int b = (int) int2;

    printf("%d\n%d", a, b);
}
```

Notes: one issue I see with the way pointers are used in your example is that there is no memory in which they are pointing to and I do believe scanf does not allocate memory for a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

> It still says error: cast from pointer to integer of different size

You aren't casting "double to int"... you're casting "double* to int."

Change

```
int a = (int) (int1);
/*             ^^^^ this is a pointer */
```

to

```
int a = (int) (*int1);
/*             ^^^^^ this is a double */
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Lines

```
scanf("%lf", int1);
scanf("%lf", int2);
```

To

```
scanf("%lf", &int1);           //Use '&'
scanf("%lf", &int2);
```

dont use pointer variable for this.

Comment: This still gives me the error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]

Answer (score 0):

What your program should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    double value1;
    double value2;

    printf("Put in two numbers:");
    scanf("%lf", &value1);
    scanf("%lf", &value2);

    int a = value1;
    int b = value2;

    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
}
```

The parameter passed to `scanf` needs to be the address of an appropriate variable. So you need to declare the variable, e.g. `double value1` and then pass the address of that variable to `scanf`, e.g. `scanf(..., &value1);`.

The C language supports implicit casting of `double` to `int`, so you don't need a cast at all.  The implicit conversion will truncate the number. If you want the number rounded to the nearest `int`, then you will need to use the `round` function.